# Pintura OR Perserve 2.0 - Production Ready?

Tags: nosql, serverside-javascript

I'm very interested in this framework, coupled with a NoSQL backend like MongoDB.

Basically, my blue-sky vision is this:

ExtJS/Pintura/MongoDB.

I would probably plug in Rhino as the js engine.

Is there anybody here using Pintura in a production environment?

What are the pitfalls?  What is your general experience?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Very excited about Pintura too, but I'm struggling getting this setup right now. Personally one of my requirements for something that's production ready would be good documentation. It's a bit confused right now, unsure of how much of the old Persevere docs are applicable, and I had to do a lot of manual changes before I could get the /example that came with Pintura to run.

In conclusions: looks like Alpha software to me!